# Padding dublicate in scrolling div, works in edge but not in chrome

Tags: html, css

I use padding-bottom in my project to get an aspect ratio, but the padding-bottom duplicate itself inside the overflow works in edge, but not in chrome.
What can I do to fix the problem and so it works in chrome to? :)

Link to codepen: https://codepen.io/mullermeck/pen/byKeWX

```css
 .scroll {
    width: 50%;
    height: 0;
    padding-bottom: 300px;
    background-color: green;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.test1{
    height: 0;
    width: 31.333%;
    padding-bottom: 31.333%;
    top: 0;
    background-color: deeppink;
    margin: 1% 1% 1% 1%;
    float: left;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="scroll">
  <div class="test1"></div>
  <div class="test1"></div>
  <div class="test1"></div>
  <div class="test1"></div>
  <div class="test1"></div>
  <div class="test1"></div>
  <div class="test1"></div>
  <div class="test1"></div>
  <div class="test1"></div>
  <div class="test1"></div>
  <div class="test1"></div>
  <div class="test1"></div>
  <div class="test1"></div>
  <div class="test1"></div>
  <div class="test1"></div>
</div>
```

I have done research but haven't found any answers to it...
this is also my first post on here so it may be wrong

Comment: No clue what you mean, or where exactly it is supposed to “duplicate” anything. Guess you might just want to remove `height: 0; padding-bottom: 300px;` from `.scroll` …?

Answer (score 1):

padding bottom is not proper solution for it.. maybe below css may help you

```
.scroll {
    width: 50%;
    height:300px;
    background-color: green;
    overflow: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.test1{
    height: 0;
    width: 31.333%;
    padding-bottom: 31.333%;
    top: 0;
    background-color: deeppink;
    margin: 1% 1% 1% 1%;
    float: left;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

Comment: it's a part of a more complex website, rectangular divs are depended on wide and they are a consistent aspect ratio. I can't put a var to hight that is calculating from wide, it will do take from the % height instead of wide

Answer (score 0):

Try this I think it's useful for you to remove the **padding-bottom: 300px;** property and in place of **height: 0;** you have to use **height: auto;**.

```css
 .scroll {
    width: 50%;
    height: auto;
/*     padding-bottom: 300px; */
    background-color: green;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.test1{
    height: 0;
    width: 31.333%;
    padding-bottom: 31.333%;
    top: 0;
    background-color: deeppink;
    margin: 1% 1% 1% 1%;
    float: left;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="scroll">
  <div class="test1"></div>
  <div class="test1"></div>
  <div class="test1"></div>
  <div class="test1"></div>
  <div class="test1"></div>
  <div class="test1"></div>
  <div class="test1"></div>
  <div class="test1"></div>
  <div class="test1"></div>
  <div class="test1"></div>
  <div class="test1"></div>
  <div class="test1"></div>
  <div class="test1"></div>
  <div class="test1"></div>
  <div class="test1"></div>
</div>
```